# Infinite-dimensional inner product spaces: if $A^k = I$ for self-adjoint $A$ and for integer $k > 0$, then $A^2 = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Exercise 5(d), Sec 80, Pg 162, PR Halmos's Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces:

If $A^k = I$ where $A$ is a self-adjoint operator and $k > 0$ is some positive integer, show that $A^2 = I$. The underlying inner product space is not necessarily finite-dimensional.

---

I see that it is rather straightforward to establish the result in finite-dimensional spaces (over both real and complex fields), using the Spectral Theorem for self-adjoint operators. However, I'm finding it difficult to extend the result to infinite dimensions for $k \geq 3$. Towards showing $A^2 = I$, my (unsuccessful) attempts so far have been around establishing $\Vert A^2x-x\Vert = 0$. Would appreciate some help. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any inner product space, complete or not, let $v$ be any vector and consider the finite-dimensional subspace generated from $v,Av,\ldots,A^{k-1}v$. Then this space is $A$-invariant, so $A$ restricted to it is a symmetric matrix. As mentioned in the question, it is straightforward to show that $A^2=I$ in this space, that is, $A^2v=v$. Since this is true of any vector, $A^2=I$.

Comment: Thanks! If $w$ is an arbitrary vector outside the finite-dimensional subspace suggested by you, then I'm unclear on why $A^2w = w$ holds. Could you kindly explain?

Comment: Apply the argument to the subspace generated by $w,Aw,\ldots,A^{k-1}w$.

Comment: Oh yes. It was a stupid question from me. You had already said "let $v$ be any vector". Your proof is remarkably easy to follow! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ is self-adjoint, all eigenvalues of $A$ are real. Also, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ implies $Av=\lambda v$ for some non-zero $v$, i.e. $v=A^kv=\lambda^kv$. So, $\lambda^k=1\implies \lambda=\pm 1$.

Now, $0=A^k-I=\prod_j(A -\xi_jI)$, where $\xi_j$ are $k$-th roots of unity. Since, $\pm 1$ are the only eigenvalues of $A$, we have $(A-\xi_j I)u\not=0$ for any non-zero vector $u$ if $\xi_j\not=\pm 1$. In other words, $\prod_{\xi_j\not=\pm 1}(A-\xi_jI)$ is injective. But, $\prod_j(A -\xi_jI)=0$, so $A^2=I$.

$\textbf{Edit:---}$ So, let $T:=(A^2-I)\prod_{\xi_j\not=\pm 1}(A-\xi_jI)$. Then, $T=0$. Note that either $A-I$ or $A+I$ or both are factors of $\prod_{j}(A-\xi_jI)=0$. Also, let $S=\prod_{\xi_j\not=\pm 1}(A-\xi_jI)$, then, $T=S(A^2-I)=(A^2-I)S$, and $S$ is injective. Therefore, for any $v\not=0$, we have $0=0(v)=T(v)=S\big((A^2-I)v\big)$. If, $(A^2-I)v=0$ we are done, but if $w:=(A^2-I)v\not=0$, then $S(w)=0$, contradicts the fact that $S$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks. However, in case of infinite-dimensional inner product spaces, is there a way to claim that $\lambda = \pm 1 \implies A^2x = x$ for all vectors in the space (especially non-eigenvectors)?

Comment: Minimal polynomial

Comment: Does the minimal polynomial result work in infinite-dimensional spaces too?

Comment: without minimal polynomial, check my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I understood all what you have stated, except for the concluding step: "so $A^2 = I$". Pardon me for a possibly dumb question here, but could you kindly elaborate how to show $A^2 = I$ based on that $\prod_j (A-\xi_jI) = 0$ and that $\prod_{\xi_j \neq \pm 1} (A-\xi_jI)$ is injective?

Comment: So, let $T:=(A^2-I)\prod_{\xi_j\not=\pm 1}(A-\xi_jI)$. Then, $T=0$. Note that either $A-I$ or $A+I$ or both are factors of $\prod_{j}(A-\xi_jI)=0$. Also, let $S=\prod_{\xi_j\not=\pm 1}(A-\xi_jI)$, then, $T=S(A^2-I)=(A^2-I)S$, and $S$ is injective. Therefore, for any $v\not=0$, we have $0=0(v)=T(v)=S\big((A^2-I)v\big)$. If, $(A^2-I)v=0$ we are done, but if $w:=(A^2-I)v\not=0$, then $S(w)=0$, contradicts the fact that $S$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

The spectrum of $A$ must be a subset of $\{-1,1\}$ by the spectral mapping theorem and the fact that $A$ is self-adjoint. Hence $A$ is unitary and $A=A^*=A^{-1}$, so $A^2=I$.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sure if the Spectral Theorem applies to infinite-dimensional inner product spaces in general. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it does, it applies to Banach algebras in general. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem.

Comment: My understanding is that the extensions of the Spectral Theorem apply to only some infinite-dimensional inner product spaces, not all, and that too under certain restrictions on operators. The Wikipedia page in fact mentions this remark at one place: "If the compactness assumption is removed, it is not true that every self-adjoint operator has eigenvectors." In other words, it does appear that the Spectral Theorem is not generally available in case of infinite-dimensional inner product spaces.

Comment: That's for the spectral theorem. The spectral mapping theorem states that the spectral values of an operator in a Banach space (including Hilbert spaces) satisfy the same relation as the operator $f(\sigma(A))=\sigma(f(A))$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra; in your case, $\lambda^k-1=\sigma(A^k-I)=0$.

Comment: Am I right to understand that the space must be a Banach space (i.e., a complete normed space) for your claim to apply? If yes, then my concern is that the space in the question is not given to be complete ...

Comment: Yes the general theorem assumes completeness. See my other answer for another take on this problem that does not assume ompleteness.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P=A^2=A^\ast A$ and $S=P^{k-1}+P^{k-2}+\cdots+P+I$. By the given conditions, $P$ is a positive operator, $S$ is strictly positive and $S(P-I)=P^k-I=A^{2k}-I=0$. Hence $\langle S(P-I)x,(P-I)x\rangle=0$ for every vector $x$. As $S$ is strictly positive, this implies that $(P-I)x=0$ for every $x$. Therefore $P=I$.